# A question on boundary of open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ have the usual topologies. Is there an open set $N\subseteq \mathbb Q\times \mathbb R$ (with product topology) such that for every non-empty open subset $U\subseteq N$, the boundary of $U$ is not compact?

Comment: @Seirios $N$ should be non-empty.

Comment: @Seirios The boundary of the empty set is empty.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question...

Comment: Didn't you post the exact same question yesterday? Why did you delete it?

Comment: [Link to the original copy of the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/426706/264) (visible only to 10k+ users now that its deleted). aliakbar, note that [this behavior is considered inappropriate here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10024/264). Please don't do it again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no non-empty open set in that space has compact boundary, and that that can be shown by first proving that any bounded open set in the usual plane has a point on its boundary with an irrational first coordinate, but I'm getting stuck there.

Comment: In any case, it should be clear that the question of whether there is such an $N$ is equivalent to the question of whether every bounded, nonempty open set has non-compact boundary.

Comment: @dfeuer: There are nonempty subsets with compact boundary. The simplest is probably the complement of a point.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, there aren't nonempty *open* bounded sets with compact boundary in that space. See Jim Belk's answer below. I was nearing the end of a similar but less elegant argument when he posted.

Comment: @dfeuer: Now that you've added the hypothesis "bounded," I agree with you.

Comment: @dfeuer: I omitted the word "open" by mistake, but notice the complement of a point is open.

Comment: I added it before you posted your comment, but perhaps after you started drafting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Let $N = (0,1)^2 \cap (\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R})$, and let $U\subseteq N$ be a nonempty open subset of $N$.  I claim that $\partial U$ is not compact.

Let $p_1\colon \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be projection onto the first coordinate.  Then $p_1(U)$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Since the extreme points of any vertical cross-section of $U$ lie in the boundary, we know that $p_1(\partial U) \supseteq p_1(U)$, and therefore $p_1(\partial U)$ contains an open interval $(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.  This in turn contains a nondegenerate closed interval $[c,d]\cap \mathbb{Q}$.  This is a closed subset of $p_1(\partial U)$ which is not compact, so $p_1(\partial U)$ cannot be compact, and hence $\partial U$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible for you to explain $p_{1}(U)\subseteq p_{1}(\partial U)$?

Comment: Let $x \in p_1(U)$. Then $\{y \in [-1,1]^2: \{x\}\times(-\infty, y] \cap U = \varnothing \}$ is nonempty and bounded above, so it has a supremum $y_0$, which you should be able to convince yourself is in that set. Then you should be able to convince yourself that $(x,y_0)$ is in the boundary of $U$.

Comment: @dfeuer Thank you very much.